# Android, reuse same activity from notification click

Tags: android, notifications, android-pendingintent

I'm trying to navigate to a fragment when the notification is clicked.

This doesn't work, it destroys the current activity (which is the same one I would use) and a new one is created:

```
val intent = Intent(applicationContext, HomeActivity::class.java).apply {
   flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP
}
val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(applicationContext, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)
```

This also does not work, same behavior as the previous one:

```
val pendingIntent = NavDeepLinkBuilder(applicationContext)
                                    .setComponentName(HomeActivity::class.java)
                                    .setGraph(R.navigation.mobile_navigation)
                                    .setDestination(R.id.myFragment)
                                    .createPendingIntent()
```

### My target

I would simply like to reuse the same activity without destroying it and navigating to the `myFrgament`.

Comment: Did you tried by removing Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately it produce the same behavior.

Comment: What about not setting any flags?

Comment: The same.

`val intent = Intent(applicationContext, HomeActivity::class.java)
val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(applicationContext, 0, intent, 0)`

Comment: Please post your manifest entry for `HomeActivity`.

Comment: Using `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` will definitely cause Android to finish the existing instance and create a new one. If you use `FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP` this should be enough to cause Android to reuse the existing instance. In this case, you should see a call to `HomeActivity.onNewIntent()`. Can you add logging to see if `HomeActivity.onCreate()` is being called?

Comment: Have you found any solution? I am facing the same issue. Also I am trying to navigate through `nav_graphs`